# c++ opengl how can i make a shader file and use it in main cpp

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw

i want to make opengl read the shader file and use it in the main cpp

i tried the tutorial in thechernoproject channel but there's a problem

```
struct ShaderProgramSource
{
    std::string VertexSource;
    std::string FragmentSource;
};
static ShaderProgramSource ParseShader(const std::string& filepath) {
    std::fstream stream(filepath);

    enum class ShaderType {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };

    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;
    while (getline(stream, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos) {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos) {
                ShaderType type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            }
            else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos) {
                ShaderType type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ss[int(type)] << line << '\n';
        }
    }
    return{ ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
}
```

i expected it will work but it don't show it's get the file

Answer (score 1):

The code which you've provided in the question, seems to read some extra information of the file, which is not part of the [OpenGL Shading Language](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

Something like

> ```non
> #shader vertex
> ```

---

If you want to read a `char` encoded text file (like a glsl file) then I recommend to use [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)

```cpp
std::ifstream sourceFile(filepath, std::fstream::in);
std::string sourceCode;
if (sourceFile.is_open())
    sourceCode = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), 
                             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```